# how to write grok pattern upto particular word

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok

I need help in writing grok pattern for upto particular string.

I have below types log lines in same log file:

**line 1:**

```
20151012 00:59:03 main ERROR java.lang.Class - Failed to retrieve the node - unable to resolve the path //mbeans/mbean[@id="audit-config"]/mbean-attributes
```

**line 2:**

```
20151012 00:59:59 RMI TCP Connection(5)-176.66.1.39 INFO  net.cp.cluster.configstore.admin.impl.AdminManager - config up-to-date; local anchor [ac6c08e5-cded-43ca-8cb3-e8be1b85c453] - global anchor: [ac6c08e5-cded-43ca-8cb3-e8be1b85c453]
```

here now, I want LOGLEVEL words like ERROR or INFO into severity field.

**My goal is, I want everything after seconds field upto ERROR or INFO in one field.**

how should I do that?

I have tried below grok but its not working:

```
%{YEAR}%{MONTHNUM}%{MONTHDAY}\s*%{HOUR}:%{MINUTE}:%{SECOND}\s*\(?<rawinfo>/^(?:(?!\s*\b(?:ERROR | ?:INFO)\b).)*/\)
```

Any help here?

Thanks!

Comment: `%{YEAR}%{MONTHNUM}%{MONTHDAY} %{TIME} %{GREEDYDATA:onefield} %{LOGLEVEL} %{GREEDYDATA:log_message}`

Comment: yeah.. its working.. thanks..